# How do I use to the zsh 'command' option to execute a the builtin 'source' command?

Tags: zsh

I am trying to log each time my shell sources a file. I am using zsh, so I went into zshenv and added this function.

```
source() {
    echo "sourcing $1"
    command source $1
}
```

The idea is everytime "source [file]" appears in one of my dotfiles and is executed, it should print the action to terminal first, before actually sourcing the file.

instead i'm getting some errors like this

```
sourcing /Users/js/.cargo/env
source:2: command not found: source
sourcing /Users/js/.sources/postgres-env.sh
source:2: command not found: source
sourcing /Users/js/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh
source:2: command not found: source
sourcing /Users/js/.iterm2_shell_integration.zsh
source:2: command not found: source
```

What is the correct way to use the shell 'command' option with zsh to call source here?

Comment: In zsh, `command x` interprets `x` as an external command. You can not run internal commands with it. This is AFIK different from i.e. bash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`command` is intended to specifically invoke *external* commands. For example if you have an alias or function for `git`, `command git` will bypass those.

You're looking for the `builtin` command to limit command lookup to only builtin commands.

```
source() {
    echo "sourcing $1"
    builtin source "$1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For it to work regardless of shell, you could use this instead:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

source() {
  echo "sourcing $1"
  . "$1"
}

source "$1"
```

Comment: Close, but not exactly what the OP wants. Note that in zsh, `source` and `.` behave slightly different, so your `source` function would not just log what's going on, but also have a different semantic from the builtin `source` command.